# Javascript won't go past the first two lines of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this code:

```
        if (div == '') {
            console.log("hi"),
            document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = first,
            $('draggablelamb').addClass('fade'),
            $('droppable').addClass('bowl');
        }
```

When the user presses a button (there are variables that I have left out and the `elseif` and `else` statements). However, when I run it in the browser it only goes past the first two lines of code (`console.log("hi")` and `document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = first`) and then skips the rest and goes onto the next `elseif`. Why is it doing it? How can I stop it from doing this?

Update:

I now know that it goes past all the lines of code by using this:

```
        console.log("Hi");
        document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = first;
        console.log("Hello again");
        $('draggablelamb').addClass('fade');
        console.log("Bonjour");
        $('droppable').addClass('bowl');
        console.log("Guten Tag");
```

but just maybe doesn't carry it out?

Comment: Why are you placing commas at the end of your lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (div == '') {
    console.log("hi");
    $('#divd').html(first);
    $('.draggablelamb').addClass('fade');
    $('.droppable').addClass('bowl');
}
```

**1.** You had commas `,` at the end of each line. It should be semi-colons `;`.

**2.** You were selecting elements by class but missing the full-stop class selector `.`. So you had `$('draggablelamb')` when it should be `$('.draggablelamb')`.

**3.** You've used jQuery for the selectors, so you can also use jQuery to write the innerHTML. Like this `$('#divd).html(first);`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `,` from the end of the first three statements.

Try,

```
    if (div == '') {
        console.log("hi");
        document.getElementById('divd').innerHTML = first;
        $('.draggablelamb').addClass('fade'); // add dot in the selector if it is a class
        $('.droppable').addClass('bowl'); // add dot in the selector if it is a class
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are looking for the *elements* `draggablelamb` and `droppable`, but they won't find any, as there are no such elements in HTML.

Searching for something that isn't there will result in an empty jQuery object, and it will still accept calls that would change the elements in it, and simply do nothing.

If you are looking for elements with classes by those names, you need periods before the class names in the selectors:

```
$('.draggablelamb').addClass('fade');
$('.droppable').addClass('bowl');
```

Also, as Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy pointed out, commas aren't used between statements in Javascript. Although it would still work in this case, because there is a comma operator that can be used between expressions, it can cause problems in other cases.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, why would it fail?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Why do you think that it wouldn't work?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: now I think about it, I don't know.